# DataBinding is not working properly in custom list itemrenderer

Tags: ipad, apache-flex, mobile, air

I am developing iPad application using Flex/Air. 
I have problem with data binding in custom list item renderer.

I have list with a collection of Classes as data provider.
Each class have a static property enabled. I display each class using an item renderer, where my item renderer is enabled when the Class  property is enabled.

The classes look like that:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public static const var name:String = "My Class";
   private static var enabled:Boolean = false;


   [Bindable]
    public static function get enabled():Boolean
    {
        return enabled;
    }

    public static function set enabled(value:Boolean):Boolean
    {
        enabled = value;
    }

}
```

Then I have the list:

```
<list dataProvider={new ArrayCollection([MyClass])} itemRenderer="CustomItemRenderer"/>
```

And the CustomItemRenderer looks like that:

```
<s:ItemRenderer autoDrawBackground="false" enabled={data.enabled}>

   <s:label text={data.name}/>

<s:/ItemRenderer>
```

So when I change the enabeled property of MyClass, the list is not updated.
The item renderer is still disabeled.

```
MyClass.enabeled = true;
```

Do you have any idea what the problem can be?

Thank you in advance!
Ivan

Comment: Please share some code. For instance I have no idea what this means "I display each class using an item renderer, where my item renderer is enabled when the Class property is enabled."  You can't change properties on classes--unless they are static properties which is probably not the case here.  You must change them on an instance of the class. What properties are you changing; how are you changing them?  You may need to call itemUpdated on the ArrayCollection

Comment: Hello, I have shared some example. I hope it will help you better understand my problem. Thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I edited the code without IDE, it should be correct thought):

```
// to dispatch a custom event your class needs to extends the EventDispatcher Class.
public class MyClass extends EventDispatcher
{
   public static const var name:String = "My Class";
   private static var _enabled:Boolean = false;


    // getter & setter with dispatchEvent could not be static...
    // instead the getter/setter for enabled, will change the static _enabled value.    
   [Bindable(event="enabledChange")]
    public function get enabled():Boolean
    {
        return _enabled;
    }

    public function set enabled(value:Boolean):void
    {
        _enabled = value;
        dispatchEvent(new Event("enabledChange"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I need to access the setter statically: MyClass.enabled;
As you see the dataProvider for the list is a collection with Classes.
Then the data property of the itemRenderer is a Class and I need to acces a property of this class but not using a instance of a class

Comment: Afaik in actionscript it is not possibile to dispatchEvent on static class/property... so you probably need to change your logic..

Comment: I understand! Thank you for spending the time to help me!